# Embedding .jar to an html error ( Incompatible magic value 1008813135)

Tags: java, html, netbeans, jar, applet

I've searched a lot and i couldnt find a solution. I've created an applet using NetBeans IDE 7.31.
When testing it in my computer it runs perfecty.
But when trying to run it from a webpage an error message appears ("Incompatible magic value 1008813135 in Japplet/Main")
Here you can find de webpage [link](http://intsoftmitec.netii.net/Main.html)
The main class its called "Main.class" and its located on the package called "Japplet".The jar file its called "GeneticaVaq.jar"
This is the html code i've used:

```
<APPLET CODE="Japplet.Main.class" archive="GeneticaVaq.jar"  WIDTH="700" HEIGHT="500"> </APPLET>
```

Does anyone knows whats causing this problem?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The magic number for a class is binary values in the class file. The .class file you are using is probably not valid.  Open the class file in a hex editor and see what's there. It should look like this: ca fe ba be in the first 4 bytes.

Comment: BTW 1008813135 is "<!DO"